# What are the best values for Postgresql.conf for better performance

Tags: database, postgresql, database-tuning

I am using a DBMS PostgreSQL 9.0.1 on S.O Linux Debian 8 and server HP proliant Ml110-G9 :
Processador: (1) Intel Xeon E5-1603v3 (2.8GHz/4-core/10MB/140W)
Memória RAM: 8GB DDR4
Disco Rígido: SATA 1TB 7.2K rpm LFF
More specifications here: [https://www.hpe.com/us/en/product-catalog/servers/proliant-servers/pip.specifications.hpe-proliant-ml110-gen9-server.7796454.html](http://Link%20to%20specification)
154/5000

See Below parameters presents in postgresql.conf. You would indicate which value for example: `cpu_index_tuple_cost` and other `CPU_*`, based on this
Server. So I do not have to use default values.

```
#seq_page_cost = 1.0
#random_page_cost = 4.0
#cpu_tuple_cost = 0.01
#cpu_index_tuple_cost = 0.005
#cpu_operator_cost = 0.0025
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 2GB
effective_cache_size = 6GB
work_mem = 52428kB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
checkpoint_segments = 128
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 500
```

Comment: You should read the explanation of each parameter in the [**manual**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-resource.html). And that is a question for dba.exchange The most important are `shared_buffers` and `work_mem`. But a SSD do marvels for performance. Also you should think in upgrade postgresql to a newer version.

Comment: Step one: Replace that SATA spinning drive with an SSD. The difference is so big that anything you do to tune your database will pale in comparison.